# modify content of http response via haproxy

Tags: response, haproxy

i'm routing a soap requests via a haproxy and one of the systems responding to requests changed ist response structure by adding namespaces to the XML Elements `<myresponse>` became `<newnamespace:myresponse>` after a new version was deployed.

a client system that i dont have under my control can't handle the changes to the payload. since i cant Change the Code of this Client i want to delete `newnamespace:` from the response payload via haproxy.

i've tried Option `rspirep ^:\ "mynewnamespace:" ""` within my backend configuration but it had no effect whatsoever

is that possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the section [what HAProxy is and is not](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/intro.html#3.1) we can read, HAProxy is not:

> a data scrubber : it will not modify the body of requests nor responses.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar problems serveral months ago, and I saw this answer. Now that I found a way to solve it, I want to post my method to help others who might get turned away. Although frankly speaking, it might be an overkill for you problem

as MoEmEn mentioned, haproxy will not modify the body of requests nor responses. However, in [haproxy's configuration guide](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#9), it mentions the ability to add some filters, and one of them allow you to compress the body requests. This definitely modifies the body.

in [one of haproxy's documentation](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/doc/internals/filters.txt), it explains how to implement a filter yourself. Basically it allows you to inspect the http request/response at every parsing stage. when something is done, it calls the callback function you defined in the filter, and then you can do anything you want with that data. the filter callbacks looks like below:

```
struct flt_ops {
    /*
     * Callbacks to manage the filter lifecycle
     */
    int  (*init)             (struct proxy *p, struct flt_conf *fconf);
    void (*deinit)           (struct proxy *p, struct flt_conf *fconf);
    int  (*check)            (struct proxy *p, struct flt_conf *fconf);
    int  (*init_per_thread)  (struct proxy *p, struct flt_conf *fconf);
    void (*deinit_per_thread)(struct proxy *p, struct flt_conf *fconf);

    /*
     * Stream callbacks
     */
    int  (*attach)            (struct stream *s, struct filter *f);
    int  (*stream_start)      (struct stream *s, struct filter *f);
    int  (*stream_set_backend)(struct stream *s, struct filter *f, struct proxy *be);
    void (*stream_stop)       (struct stream *s, struct filter *f);
    void (*detach)            (struct stream *s, struct filter *f);
    void (*check_timeouts)    (struct stream *s, struct filter *f);

    /*
     * Channel callbacks
     */
    int  (*channel_start_analyze)(struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                  struct channel *chn);
    int  (*channel_pre_analyze)  (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                  struct channel *chn,
                                  unsigned int an_bit);
    int  (*channel_post_analyze) (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                  struct channel *chn,
                                  unsigned int an_bit);
    int  (*channel_end_analyze)  (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                  struct channel *chn);

    /*
     * HTTP callbacks
     */
    int  (*http_headers)       (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg);
    int  (*http_data)          (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg);
    int  (*http_chunk_trailers)(struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg);
    int  (*http_end)           (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg);
    int  (*http_forward_data)  (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg,
                                unsigned int len);

    void (*http_reset)         (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                struct http_msg *msg);
    void (*http_reply)         (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                                short status,
                                const struct buffer *msg);

    /*
     * TCP callbacks
     */
    int  (*tcp_data)        (struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                             struct channel *chn);
    int  (*tcp_forward_data)(struct stream *s, struct filter *f,
                             struct channel *chn,
                             unsigned int len);
};
```

the ones you might be interested in is

```
http_data
```

as you are going to remove the prefix "newnamespace:". Haproxy offers a nice function to easily remove something:

```
/* This function writes the string <str> at position <pos> which must be in
 * buffer <b>, and moves <end> just after the end of <str>. <b>'s parameters
 * <l> and <r> are updated to be valid after the shift. The shift value
 * (positive or negative) is returned. If there's no space left, the move is
 * not done. The function does not adjust ->o because it does not make sense to
 * use it on data scheduled to be sent. For the same reason, it does not make
 * sense to call this function on unparsed data, so <orig> is not updated. The
 * string length is taken from parameter <len>. If <len> is null, the <str>
 * pointer is allowed to be null.
 */
int buffer_replace2(struct buffer *b, char *pos, char *end, const char *str, int len)
```

say you find "newnamespace:" begins at char* pos, and ends at char* end, you can call

```
buffer_replace2(buf, pos, end, NULL, 0)
```

to remove the string.

although this might be a little too much, it will solve your problem